# Unable to copy files on FTP server.

Tags: c#, asp.net, ftp

```
Copying all files to temporary location below for package/publish:
    obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp.
    2>Publishing folder /...
    2>Unable to add 'index.aspx' to the Web site.  Access is denied (550).
    2>Unable to add 'jquery-1.7.1.min.js' to the Web site.  Access is denied (550).
    2>Unable to add 'jquery.dropotron-1.0.js' to the Web site.  Access is denied (550).
    2>Unable to add 'style.css' to the Web site.  Access is denied (550).
    2>Unable to add 'Web.config' to the Web site.  Access is denied (550).
    2>Unable to add folder 'bin' to the Web site.  Cannot create folder "bin".
    2>Unable to add folder 'images' to the Web site.  Cannot create folder "images".
    2>Site was published successfully ftp://myblogstory.somee.com/
    2>
    ========== Build: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
    ========== Publish: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

My login is correct so i shuld have permission to do that. Any thoughts ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 550 error can appear when you don't have write access to the folder you are trying to upload (or the file you are trying to edit).

Given the messages you posted, you are trying to upload files to the root of the FTP. It is possible that you need to upload your files to a subfolder, usually (but not always) is `/wwwroot` in Windows hosting.

It also might be that your FTP credentials have only read rights, thus you can not put any files or folders in the FTP server.

Try and check your FTP credentials with an FTP client (e.g. FileZilla) to see if you can directly upload files and create folders.

Comment: Thank you coodi,

there was problem  with that root, shuld have copy it to root subfolder and now its working !